# cant update defaultdict in string format method

Tags: python, format, defaultdict

I am trying to generate random color for each user name.

When I wrote this code name1 and name2 had the same color. What is wrong here?

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def get_color():
    print('call')
    return ''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])

colors = defaultdict(get_color)

msg1 = {'name' : 'name1'}
msg2 = {'name' : 'name2'}

for msg in [msg1, msg2]:
    msg = '{colors[name]} {name}'.format(colors=colors, **msg)
    print(msg)
```

Output:

> call
>
> 72C44D name1
>
> 72C44D name2

Thank you

Comment: I ran the code. It generates the same code for any string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing `colors` after the loop is done will show you

```
defaultdict(<function get_color at 0x7f6e7faed1e0>, {'name': '67C80A'})
```

i.e. `color` has only a single key. You are accessing `colors['name']` with a hardcoded key `'name'`, not `colors[name]` with a dynamic name.

You need one more formatting step. One to build the template, another to insert `colors[name]` into the template.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def get_color():
    print('call')
    return ''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])

colors = defaultdict(get_color)

msg1 = {'name' : 'name1'}
msg2 = {'name' : 'name2'}

for msg in [msg1, msg2]:
    msg_template = '{{colors[{name}]}} {{name}}'.format(**msg)
    print(msg_template) # for demo purposes
    msg = msg_template.format(colors=colors, **msg)
    print(msg)
```

Output

```
{colors[name1]} {name}
call
A70B47 name1
{colors[name2]} {name}
call
55709A name2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `get_colors()` only once and assign the stored color ( in `colors` ) to both messages. Do it like the following to generate a random color for each iteration:

```
for msg in [msg1, msg2]:
    msg = '{colors[name]} {name}'.format(colors=defaultdict(get_color), **msg)
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I separated the generate from the print, to make it easier to read. You can simplify your code and it will be much easier.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def generate_color():
    color = ''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])
    print ('generate_color returns', color)
    return color

colors = defaultdict(generate_color)

# simplify this. It's just a list of names
names = ['name1', 'name2']

# to call generate_color once for each name, 
# all you need to do is access that name in the default dict
print ('building colors')
for name in names:
    colors[name]

# now you have populated colors.
print ('printing colors')
for key in colors:
    # I went with simplifying the format string
    print ('{} {}'.format(key, colors[key]))
```